# Regex Constraint in Attribute parameter throwing error

Tags: c#, regex, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I think I am doing this constraint wrong. I want the year to be 4 digits, the month to be 2 digits, and the month to range from 1 to 12:

```cs
[Route("projects/released/{year:regex(\\d{4})}/{month:regex(\\d{2}):range(1,12)}")]
```

I get the following error in rider:

> Route parameter constraint **'regex(\d{2'** not resolved

I'm running .NET 6 ASP.NET Core MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```cs
[Route("projects/released/{year:regex(^\\d{{4}}$)}/{month:regex(^\\d{{2}}$):range(1,12)}")]
public IActionResult Index(string year, string month)
{
    // your code...
}
```

See detailed description in the documentation: [Regular expressions in constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#regular-expressions-in-constraints)

***Pay attention**: to escape routing parameter delimiter characters `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, double the characters in the expression, for example, `{{`, `}}`, `[[`, `]]`.*

Comment: Ok I see. So the beginning ^ and ending $ contains the inline constraint. Thank you!